# The WebSocket instance cannot be used for communication because it has been transitioned into an invalid state

Tags: asp.net, iis, episerver, iis-10, episerver-10

I have the latest version of EpiServer on my Windows server 2016 and almost every minute I have this warning on my event log:

> WebSocketException
>
> The WebSocket instance cannot be used for communication because it has been transitioned into an invalid state. at System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocket.ThrowIfAborted() at System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocket.CloseAsyncImpl(WebSocketCloseStatus closeStatus, String statusDescription, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean performValidation) at System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus closeStatus, String statusDescription, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at EPiServer.Shell.UI.Messaging.Internal.DefaultWebSocketHandler.d__7.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at EPiServer.Shell.UI.Messaging.Internal.PushMessageHandler.d__7.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.WebSocketPipeline.d__9.MoveNext()

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is web sockets enabled on the server?

Comment: @TedNyberg thanks for response. You mean the role in Server Roles>Web Server (IIS)>...> web sockets? Yes I've installed that

Comment: Is this a front end server behind firewalls or so?

Comment: @EricHerlitz, Thanks for reply. Of course The server is behind a firewall, but the frontend and backend are on the same server/application pool. Did I get your question correctly?

Comment: I had the same issue on a server that was behind a firewall (check point of some sort). Web Sockets was working internally so any connections was clearly terminated by the firewall for external users. After an update of the firewall/check point things started working again.

Comment: @EricHerlitz Thanks a lot. I will ask the IT guy to check it ;)